# when we click a hyperlink in a pdf which is embedded in a sharepoint web page using content editor webpart/page viewer web part is open in new window

Tags: content-editor-web-part, pdf

I tried different solutions but nothing worked. When i click a hyperlink in a pdf which is embedded in a sharepoint 2019 web page using content editor webpart or a page viewer web part, the hyperlink opens up a page in a new window. The requirement is when we click on a hyperlink which is on a pdf it should open within the same content editor webpart borders and not on the parent page or on a new browser tab. is it possible?